# responsive collapsed borders on floated children

Tags: html, css, border-layout

I'm trying to achieve the same effect that collapsed borders have on tables and table cells but using floated divs(or inline block divs), note the design is also responsive. The markup looks a little like this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="Lev1">
    label
  </div>
  <div class="Lev1">
    <div class="lev2">list item</div>
    <div class="lev2">list item</div>
    ..variable amount of Lev2 child divs
  </div>
</div>
```

currently my css is something like this

```
.parent {
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.lev1 {
 float:left;
 border:0px;
}
.lev2 {
 float:left;
 border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

At full screen all the children stack horizontally but on resize the lev2 children begin to stack vertically and the missing top and bottom borders then becomes obvious. I would like to be able to put a 1px border around all child elements and have the borders collapse into each other.

I have tried using negative margins but they start to double up vertically and go out of whack.

Not sure if this is possible, would be great if someone has a idea.

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: The CSS class "lev1" does not equal the "Lev1"-class provided in html (capitalisation).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want but I managed to "collapse" the .lev2 div borders using negative margins.

Here is the css:

```
.lev2 {
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #000;
  margin-top:-1px;
  margin-left:-1px;
}
```

See if it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2vgo095d/)

Comment: This seems to works better if you add a background-color to .lev2 That said the last .lev2-box looks a bit differently positioned from the rest if you do.